# Button in python graphic window

Tags: python, loops, button

```
def read_inventory(fname):
    file=open(fname,'r')
    lst=file.readlines()
    return lst


while True:
    c=win.getMouse()#c=click
    if p2.x<c.x<p1.x and p2.y<c.y<p1.y:
        lst=read_inventory(file_name_E.getText())
        print(lst)
```

In a python graphic window, I'm trying to make a button that opens a file in which the name is input by the user. However, if the file does not exist, I get an error and the `while True` loop does not run anymore, meaning that the user cannot enter another file to try and open. I can't seem to understand why this is happening.

Comment: @BhargavRao I want the file to be able to take an input again and try to open that file.

Comment: Put the file open in a try except block

Comment: @BhargavRao I don't know what that is, I'll look it up, but could you also give an example?

Comment: is your intention to create a file if it doesnt exist, or tell the user that it isn't valid?

Comment: @chris neither, I wanted the program to keep running if an invalid file name was inputted.

Comment: A try except block worked, thanks @BhargavRao

Comment: Now post whatever you have done as answer. You'll help many others. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def read_inventory(fname):
    file=open(fname,'r')
    lst=file.readlines()
    return lst

while True:
        try:
            c=win.getMouse()#c=click
            if p2.x<c.x<p1.x and p2.y<c.y<p1.y:
                lst=read_inventory(file_name_E.getText())
                print(lst)
        except:
            pass
```

Comment: @BargavRao What's OP?

Answer (score 1):

The try except block worked perfectly and this is what I got:

```
def read_inventory(fname):
    file=open(fname,'r')
    lst=file.readlines()
    return lst

while True:
    c=win.getMouse() #c=click
    if p2.x<c.x<p1.x and p2.y<c.y<p1.y:
        try:
            lst=read_inventory(file_name_E.getText())
            print(lst)
        except:
            print("File name '{}' does not exist.".format(file_name_E.getText()))
```

lst is just the variable assigned to whatever is in the file at the time of reading.